# How to solve the differential equation $\,\, y'' = {(-h) / (y^2) }$

Tags: calculus

Consider the equation : $y'' = {(-h) / (y^2) }$ with
initial conditions $y(1)=2h/(k^2)$ and $\frac {dy}{dx} (1)=k$
A)solve the equation with using the initial conditions

b)Now Solve the equation $\,\,y'' = {(-h) / (y^2) } + qy\,\,$ with consideration that q is very  small.

Comment: @learner: Unfortunately, he is asking questions here without showing any attempts. :(

Answer (score 1):

a) The initial conditions given make the problem nicer. Multiply your equation by $y'$:

$$y''=-h/y^2\implies y''\, y'=-h \frac{y'}{y^2}=h\frac{d}{dt}(\dfrac{1}{y}).$$
Note that the first member in second equation is $\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{y'^2}{2})$. Integrate beetween $1$ and $t$ to get:$$y'^2=\dfrac{2h}{y}.$$
Can you continue from here? (the task is easier if you assume $h>0$, does the text of the exercise say anything about?)

Answer (score 0):

you are almost there, take the square root on both sides

$ y'(x) = \frac{ \sqrt{2h}}{\sqrt{y}} $ so $ dy\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{2h}dx$

integration gives $ (2/3)y^{3/2}=\sqrt{2h}x+c $